# React button onClick not binding event listener to window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Having some issues with attaching an onClick event to a button.  Clicking the rendered button has no effect, and inspecting the DOM shows there are no event listeners present on the page.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - but I'm pretty certain that it has to do with how my environment is set up with webpack and babel.  Problem is, I don't really know how to begin troubleshooting it.

(copy-pasting [this code](http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010) into a file and rendering it doesn't work, but it works on the codepen project)

Below is the code, just in case.

```
import React from 'react';

class Root extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.test = this.test.bind(this);
    }
    test(){
        console.log('test');
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Keep In Touch</title>
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/semantic.min.css" type="text/css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    <button className='ui primary button' onClick={this.test}>click me</button>
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I find it odd that you have `html`, `head` and `body` tags defined in your react component.  This is usually not necessary and I suspect your issue is cause by not actually having React loaded in this (sub?) page.  But without knowing how this is set up to work (I assume it is working as you are able to see the button), I cannot say for certain.

Comment: Here's the github repo - would this help?  I'm not sure what you mean by "loading React" in the sub page.  This is the first event handler for my entire project so it's entirely possible. https://github.com/timmyichen/kit

Comment: After looking it through a bit more carefully, I think this might be the culprit? Using `res.send(renderToString(<Root />));` to actually render the JSX

Comment: Yeah I'm an idiot. Thanks for setting me down the right path. Fixed it by adding an `index.html` file and using `Root.js` as my app entry point.  Many many thanks. :)

Comment: In situations like this, its often useful to write out the solution more formally as an answer and accept it yourself.  This will help anyone else who has the same issue that come across this at a later date.  Also looking at your repo, it appears though the issue was, at least partially, caused by server-side rendering (which is why I was confused as I haven't done any of that before) so perhaps mentioning that in the question, tags, or answer will also help future visitors.